# Need assistance with this if statement

Tags: c++

first, let let me show you the code:

```
// calculate grand total
if(unitsPurchased >= 10,19)
{
    discount = .20;
    totalCost = totalCost - (totalCost * discount);
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << "\tBecuase you purchased " << unitsPurchased << " Units,\n\tYou get a 20% discount!" << "The grand total is: $" << totalCost << endl;
}
```

I'm trying to apply a `20%` discount if a person buys between `10 to 19 items`. how can I alter my if statement to reflect this? I've tried using `AND (&&)` but that didn't work. how can I set the range between two numbers?

Comment: `if(unitsPurchased >= 10 && unitsPurchased <= 19)`

Comment: I'm curious. If I buy 20 items, do I get a discount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement you're looking for is one of:

```
if (unitsPurchased >  10 && unitsPurchased <  19) { // exclude 10, 19
if (unitsPurchased >= 10 && unitsPurchased <  19) { // include 10, exclude 19
if (unitsPurchased >= 10 && unitsPurchased <= 19) { // include 10, 19
```

An expression like `valA, valB` is actually a use of the comma operator which will evaluate both `valA` and `valB` but result in the *single* value `valB`.

In your particular case, it's more complicated since the comma operator has a relatively low precedence, so `unitsPurchased >= 10, 19` means `(unitsPurchased >= 10), 19`, which equates to:

- evaluate `unitsPurchased >= 10`;
- evaluate `19`;
- *use* the value `19`.

Since `19` is non-zero, it is considered true. Hence your business is more likely to go bankrupt since every single purchase results in a 20% discount :-)

Comment: "your business is more likely to go bankrupt", hahahaha, maybe that was the plan :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
if(unitsPurchased > 10 && unitsPurchased < 19){
    discount = 0.2; 
}
```

This if-statement checks if `unitsPurchased` is greater than 10 *and* if it is less than 19, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the `&&` (and) operator:

```
if(unitsPurchased >= 10 && unitsPurchased <= 19)
{
    discount = .20;
    totalCost = totalCost - (totalCost * discount);
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << "\tBecuase you purchased " << unitsPurchased << " Units,\n\tYou get a 20% discount!" << "The grand total is: $" << totalCost << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct and I want to give a heads-up if anyone comes across this.

Don’t write `10 <= unitsPurchased <= 19`. That will be a buggy statement in **many languages**(not all). If `unitsPurchased` is 20 , the first part of the statement will be correct and even though the second part is wrong, it will return `true`.

This was a mistake I made in my first ever programming exam.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(unitsPurchased > 10 && unitsPurchased < 19){
     
}
```

Do it this way.